# How Can Move the position of Footer in Magento

Tags: magento, footer

How can i change the postion of footer section in magento?

I want to put the footer in the main div of the page.

How can i dothis in magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, maybe reorganising your page structure would be a better option - a footer is a footer and not really part of the main content.

Nonetheless, this can be easily achieved using layout xml.

**EDIT**

There are two methods you can employ:

**1. Use a local xml file for your base layout overrides.** - `app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/layout/local.xml`

This should really be your preferred method, unless there is a good argument against for your particular use case.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="unsetChild">
                <alias>footer</alias>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <action method="insert">
                <alias>footer</alias>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

OR...

**2. Copy base layout files**

copy `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml` to `app/design/frontend/your_package/yout_theme/layout/page.xml`

Find the footer node which be declared as follows (in an untouched page.xml *CE 1.7*):

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
        <label>Page Footer</label>
        <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
    </block>
    <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
    <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
</block>
```

it will be a direct descendant of the root node.  Move this whole node so that it becomes a child of the main content node:

```
<block type="core/text_list" name="content" as="content" translate="label">
    <label>Main Content Area</label>

    <block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml" after=">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.container" as="bottomContainer" translate="label">
            <label>Page Footer</label>
            <action method="setElementClass"><value>bottom-container</value></action>
        </block>
        <block type="page/switch" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="page/switch/stores.phtml"/>
        <block type="page/template_links" name="footer_links" as="footer_links" template="page/template/links.phtml"/>
    </block>
</block>
```

Remember to refresh your cache if it is enabled :)

**EDIT**

To answer the question in the comment regarding block positioning using the second method.  You can use the before and after attributes.

i.e.

```
<block type="page/html_footer" name="footer" as="footer" template="page/html/footer.phtml" after="your_sibling_block_name">
```

also, depending on the other layout xml you might also have to edit the sibling block and add a before attribute to it i.e. `before="footer"`

Comment: yes i already did this.there have silder and product section home page.So the footer part displayed in between them.That means after slider the footer part displayed then product section displayed.

Comment: Ok, so what is the block name that you are trying to have the footer come after and which of the two methods above have you used?

Comment: You can use before/after attributes. I have updated the answer for you.